# Parallel RLC transfer function

Tags: circuit-analysis, parallel, transfer-function

I want to get the transfer function of the parallel RLC circuit. Any one can help. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: $$1$$  (By the way, is this homework?  If so flag it as such please. :-)

Comment: Yes, I agree: 1.

Comment: Sajjad, is there any reason for you to expect that there is a difference between Vi and Vo?

Comment: Transfer function is usually Vo/Vi which in this case is 1 as Vo = Vi.  I suspect you are looking for something else like impedance plotted against frequency? Is so what have you tried? Happy to help on homework questions but nobody here will just do the homework for you.

Comment: If you're looking to find what the equivalent impedance is in the Laplace domain, you combine the elements as you would parallel impedances. However if you're looking for a Vo/Vi transfer function, it's equal to 1 as others have stated. A transfer function of the form Io/Vi might be more interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure this question doesn't live forever in unanaswered-question limbo,

As drawn, the voltage transfer function is identically 1, because Vo and Vi measure the voltage across the same two nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Impedance of Inductor in s domain
XL = L*s
Impedance of capacitor in s domain
Xc = 1/(C*s)

As the three elements are in parallel :
1/Ztot  = (1/Xc) + (1/XL) + (1/R)

Ztot =  (s*R*L)/(s^2*(R*L*C) + s*L + R)

The voltage input is going to be the voltage output and the transfer function would be just 1.
Instead the transfer function can be obtained for current input and voltage output.
Which is nothing but just Ztot (since impedance is equal to Voltage/Current).
The other way is not possible(Current/Voltage) as the transfer function is non-casual.

Also current input and current output through any of the elements can be found out(usually resistor's current is found out)

Ir(s)/I(s)   = (s*L)/(s^2*(R*L*C) + s*L + R)

Answer (score 0):

The transfer function for Vo/Ii is even more useful when driven by a current source/sink such as common emitter as a high Q bandpass filter with Q= R/X(f) as the impedance ratio and resonant  f/ -3dB bandwidth ratio.

Since Vo=Vi, the transfer function is the same as the input impedance curve when swept with a current source. Vi/Ii (f)

Comment: Its not a home work. actually i am doing research on equivalent circuit designing for microstrip lines. I have transfer functions of strip lines. I also thought that its TF is 1. But if we derive its characteristic equation it has 2 roots. means it has resonant frequency. my question is how it is possible that a resonator has TF=1? Another thing. The transfer function will be equal to its input impedance or admittance? @Tony Stewart

Comment: @Sajjad There is no right or wrong answer, but both Z(f) and Y(f) functions can be useful with different design methods along with Smith Charts and s matrices, but obviously TF=1 method is not useful.

Comment: So can i say that the Transfer function of this circuit is equal to its Z(s)?@Tony Stewart

Comment: transfer function or ratio as function of Z(s) or Y(s)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have complete answer nor full method, but I come across a solved example of R-L-C parallel.
And I deduce this data from what given:
Numerator will be s only.
Denominator will be quadratic equation of s.
In denominator adjusting coefficient of s as one then 1/RC will be coefficient of s and 1/LC will be constant term.